# Problem with WCF and NTLM

Tags: c#, wcf

Im trying to call an Axis Ws that has NTLM Security in it, im using BasicHttpBinding, the problem is that if i call it i get an error saying:

The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

I dont have any access to that server so i cannot look at how it is configured.

But if the call a Get with HttpWebRequest to that WS with my credentials too, and then call the ws it works fine.

Any idea on what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass your credentials when calling the web service.  Have you tried using impersonation or passing your credentials (like so)?

```
SomeService client = new SomeService();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username","password");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the following settings are set on your webserver web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">
  </system.web>
```